# Automatically delete files after x days and remove the thumbnail from the madiastore

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete pictures that I've created that are older than 3 days (I'm aware I have it set to one second in the code currently) the code works great except the thumbnail in the media store is still present and won't go away until a rescan is triggered but that feature has bee removed and I get a permission denied when I try to add that code. How do I add removal from the media store to this code as well?

```
DCIMPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString();
        path = DCIMPath + "/Signatures";


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            File directory = new File(path);
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

            if (directory.exists()) {
                File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
                long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000);
                for (File listFile : listFiles)
                    if (listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
                        listFile.delete();
                        if (!listFile.delete()) {
                            System.err.println("Unable to delete file: " + listFile);
                        }
                    }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signatures Older Than 3 Days Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: `listFile.delete();
                        if (!listFile.delete()) ` If you delete the file twice the second one will certainly fail.

Comment: `if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }` If the directory does not exist it will not contain files either. So there is nothing to delete.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My code will make the signature directory first if it does not exist. If it does exist then it will list all of the files in it and if they are after a certain age then it will delete them. This part of the code is basically used when the app is opened back up again as the first time there will obviously not be any files saved in the directory. The deleting of the old file works, the thumbnails being removed from the media store with out having to reboot the device (triggering a refresh) is the issue.